# Want last month data in Query but SOQL giving error is it supported?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

This is my query. i want last report date data.

```
SELECT ErrorCategory__c FROM Score__c 
where reportdate__C=(select max(reportdate__C) from Score__c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you have provided is not supported by SOQL. This is because [aggregate functions in SOQL](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) return its results in an array of `AggregateResult` objects. Thus, you cannot use the result directly in the SOQL, you need to fetch the value from that array of `AggregateResult` and then use that value in your SOQL.

Here is how you would do it (assuming the datatype of reportdate__c is Date):

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults  = [select max(reportdate__C)maxReportDate from Score__c];
Date maxReportDate = (Date)groupedResults[0].get('maxReportDate');

List<Score__c> scoreSoLst 
= [SELECT ErrorCategory__c FROM Score__c where reportdate__C = :maxReportDate];
```

Hope this helps.